# Simple Regular expression question

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a large malformed test HTML document which I need to get the numbers out of:

I'd like to get the primary ratio out. I'm using this regular expression:

```
(?<=Primary ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>).*(?=</TD>)
```

On this string:

```
Primary ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>10.52</TD><TD>14.97</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR align='right'><TD align='left'>Flip Ratio</TD><TD>-122.81</TD><TD>1.13</TD><TD>1.50</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR align='right'><TD align='left'>Secondary Ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>0.70</TD><TD>0.70</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR align='right'><TD align='left'>RM Ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>2.02</TD>
```

But I get this as a result:

```
10.52</TD><TD>14.97</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR align='right'><TD align='left'>Flip Ra
tio</TD><TD>-122.81</TD><TD>1.13</TD><TD>1.50</TD><TD></TD></TR><TR align='right
'><TD align='left'>Secondary Ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>0.70</TD><TD>0.70</TD><TD>
</TD></TR><TR align='right'><TD align='left'>RM Ratio</TD><TD>--</TD><TD>2.02
```

I don't want that, I just want the 10.52 number in the first tag.

I mean, it found the start of the string perfectly, but it didn't find the first .
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.*` with `.*?` near the end of your regex; that should stop it from matching too much. Normally it'll much as much as possible that fits the pattern, by adding the `?`, you ask it to match as little as possible instead.

Comment: This behaviour is known as "greedy" matching, by the way. The syntax Flynn proposes explicitly tells the regex parser to match non-greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML parser instead of a RegEx - the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good one.

In general, regular expressions are not suitable for usage with HTML, as HTML is not a regular language. This is particularly true if you are working with HTML from different sources. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a compelling demonstration.

Comment: It's a really nice malformed document. I don't know how the agility pack handles it. I'd just prefer to use regex in this case. I'll definitely keep this in mind in the future though.

Comment: @Mike - from the site: `The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML.`

Comment: That, or an XML parser. I like XPath. Also, @Mike, read the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - because it's relevant and you'll enjoy it.

Comment: If it's malformed then Flynn1179's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Lunivore - XML parsers are not suitable for valid HTML either - for example `<br>` is valid HTML (4.01), but not valid XML. Of course, XHTML is also XML, so that's a different issue.

Comment: Sure. Most modern HTML is XHTML anyway, because other people like XPath too. I think I used Regex the last time I needed to do something like this, but I acknowledge the complete unmaintainability of my code and hang my head in shame. Shame!

Comment: I also believe we are using it for different purposes. I've got a document I need to find specific information within, whereas the other question is asking about matching multiple tags. If I was parsing a HTML document to get everything inside every <P> for example, I would definitely use a HTML parser. I guess for different purposes, different tools can come into play.

Comment: @Mike - fair comment. Absolutely agree.